# How does adb -e uninstall package detect emulators? In-depth emulator detection

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, emulation

I was told that running command "`adb -e uninstall com.example.myapp`" works specifically with emulators because of the "`-e`". How does ADB know that the device is an emulator? Is there any source code available for this?

I am trying to find a more in depth way to detect emulators that does not rely on `BUILD.PROP` or any value that is easily changed. If anyone can help answer this, or direct me to any information related to more in depth emulator detection, I would appreciate it. Please don't give any information that leads to purchasing an emulator detection product.

Comment: "Please don't give any information that leads to purchasing an emulator detection product." I did not even know that existed...

Comment: There are plenty of products/services/companies that provide emulator detection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adb mostly consists of a client-server model. When you type `adb` in command line, you are using the adb-client to talk to the always-running adb-server.

adb-server "talks to devices" over two different transport mechanisms. USB and TCP. If you put in the `-e` flag, the adb-client explicitly sets its transport mechanism to *'transport-local'* (as opposed to *'transport-usb'*) and tries to connect to the adb-server at tcp:localhost:5037.

Android emulators also connect to the adb-server over TCP.

So to answer your question, if you specify `-e` for the adb client, it tries to connect over TCP to the adb-server, which checks the set transport mechanism from the client and tries to connect over either TCP for emulators or USB for actual devices. If there are more than one emulator instances running, `adb -e` will fail.

The source code for [adb is open](https://github.com/android/platform_system_core/tree/master/adb). You can look to learn more there.

Comment: Thank you very much for the informative answer and the link. You're awesome.